Send response to GPS tracking device for Login message
I am working on a project where the task is to receive location data from a GPS tracking device; Also to respond back to a few of them including Login. I went through a similar question but do not find any concluding answer on it. I have tried with java ServerSocket and ServerSocketChannel (NIO) both approches. I only keep receiving same data with a particular denoted byte login protocol despite responding 'n' number of times; Please advise if anyone has any solution; Thanks!
I Used Java ServerSocket and ServerSocketChannel (NIO)
